search and list out data from a cross table
I am trying to search for values listed in a column from multiple sheets in my Excel workbook. If Excel finds a match, I would like it to check the cell of other columns on the left of the match cell on the same row as the match data. If the cell is numeric, return the column top value, cell value in the new sheet.
Here is what I have done so far. As the item may not be in the same column in all sheets, a and b are for searching in all cells in the sheet. The code below only create new sheet and have the first row, then run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error occur.
To solve this problem, Should I need to use dictionary() to solve it.
Sub listout()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Item As String
Dim Totalsheets As Integer

'Item name
Item = "B-0-1"
Totalsheets = Worksheets.Count
Dim newsheet As Worksheet

Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Totalsheets))
newsheet.Name = Item
newsheet.Range("A1").Value = "Item"
newsheet.Range("B1").Value = "Function"
newsheet.Range("C1").Value = "Type"
newsheet.Range("D1").Value = "No."

Dim rown As Integer
rown = 1

For i = 1 To Totalsheets
lastRow = Sheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = Sheets(i).Range(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For a = 1 To lastColumn
For b = 1 To lastRow
cellvalue = Sheets(i).Cells(b, a).Value
If Item = cellvalue Then

For c = 1 To lastColumn
If IsNumeric(Sheets(i).Range(b, c)) = True Then
rown = rown + 1
fname = Sheets(i).Cells(2, c).Value
ftype = Sheets(i).Cells(1, c).Value
rpno = Sheets(i).Cells(b, c).Value
newsheet.Range("A" & rown).Value = Item
newsheet.Range("B" & rown).Value = fname
newsheet.Range("C" & rown).Value = ftype
newsheet.Range("D" & rown).Value = rpno
End If
Next c
End If
Next b
Next a
Next i
End Sub



The original data as below

I would like the result like this



Both Range() and Cells() can be used to refer a cell/range. But the syntax is different. Sheets(i).Range(b, c) should be Sheets(i).Cells(b, c).

If Sheets(i).Name <> newsheet.Name Then is used to skip the newly created sheet, which is the last one. In theory, your code doesn't interact with it. But adding the If clause makes the code more robust.

Declaring all variables is crucial to prevent coding errors.


Option Explicit
Sub listout()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Item As String, cellvalue As String
    Dim fname As String, ftype As String, rpno As Long
    Dim Totalsheets As Long, lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long, a As Long, b As Long, c As Long
    'Item name
    Item = "B-0-1"
    Totalsheets = Worksheets.Count
    Dim newsheet As Worksheet
    Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Totalsheets))
    newsheet.Name = Item
    newsheet.Range("A1").Value = "Item"
    newsheet.Range("B1").Value = "Function"
    newsheet.Range("C1").Value = "Type"
    newsheet.Range("D1").Value = "No."
    Dim rown As Integer
    rown = 1
    For i = 1 To Totalsheets
        If Sheets(i).Name <> newsheet.Name Then ' skip newsheet
            lastRow = Sheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lastColumn = Sheets(i).Cells(2, Sheets(i).Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For a = 1 To lastColumn
                For b = 1 To lastRow
                    cellvalue = Sheets(i).Cells(b, a).Value
                    If Item = cellvalue Then
                        For c = 1 To lastColumn
                            If IsNumeric(Sheets(i).Cells(b, c).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Sheets(i).Cells(b, c).Value) Then
                                rown = rown + 1
                                fname = Sheets(i).Cells(2, c).Value
                                ftype = Sheets(i).Cells(1, c).Value
                                rpno = Sheets(i).Cells(b, c).Value
                                ' populate ftype and fname for blank cell
                                If Len(ftype) = 0 Then
                                    ftype = Sheets(i).Cells(1, c).End(xlToLeft).Value
                                End If
                                If Len(fname) = 0 Then fname = ftype
                                newsheet.Range("A" & rown).Value = Item
                                newsheet.Range("B" & rown).Value = fname
                                newsheet.Range("C" & rown).Value = ftype
                                newsheet.Range("D" & rown).Value = rpno
                            End If
                        Next c
                    End If
                Next b
            Next a
        End If
    Next i
End Sub



Loading data into array to improve the processing efficiency

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRes, iR As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Const START_ROW = 3
    Const START_COL = 2
    Const ITEM_NAME = "B-0-1" ' modify as needed
    For Each oSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oSht.Name <> ITEM_NAME Then
            ' load table into array
            Set rngData = oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            arrData = rngData.Value
            ' populate blank cell in the first two rows
            arrData(2, 2) = arrData(1, 2)
            For j = START_COL + 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                If Len(arrData(1, j)) = 0 Then arrData(1, j) = arrData(1, j - 1)
            Next j
            ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData) * UBound(arrData, 2), 3)
            ' look through data row
            For i = START_ROW To UBound(arrData)
                If arrData(i, 1) = ITEM_NAME Then
                    For j = START_COL To UBound(arrData, 2)
                        ' populate output array
                        If Len(arrData(i, j)) > 0 And IsNumeric(arrData(i, j)) Then
                            iR = iR + 1
                            arrRes(iR, 0) = ITEM_NAME
                            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(2, j)
                            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(1, j)
                            arrRes(iR, 3) = arrData(i, j)
                        End If
                    Next j
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next
    Set oSht = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ITEM_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oSht Is Nothing Then ' create new sheet
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = ITEM_NAME
    Else ' clear if sheet is exists
        oSht.Cells.Clear
    End If
    ' write output to sheet
    oSht.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Item", "Function", "Type", "No.")
    oSht.Range("A2").Resize(iR, 4).Value = arrRes
End Sub

